# How can I show a youtube video in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am developing a web app to show a youtube video. The app is being developed with node.js and express . So I want to show the video in the html which is write as ejs. 
The code looks like:

```
<li>
        <video controls="true" src="<%= problem.solution %>" autoplay="none" preload="auto" width="600" height="400">
        </video>
</li>
```

But it did not play at all, can any one give me some ideas? Or some materials about how to figure it out?

Comment: try iframe to embed YouTube embedded url.

Comment: 1. add an 'id' value to your html.video.tag 2. use the id to get a ref to the node in javascript and dynamically set the value of 'myVidTag.src' to the url for the video on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe width="1020" height="815" src= <%= g.url %> ></iframe>
```

this is what I used, and it worked as the link for the video, you need to use the embed link to video.
To get the embed link, you press the share button, and there you could get a example of a iframe example with a working link.